# Excel - Search and Replace Inverted Commas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So, the issue seems to be quite trivial, but I cannot find a solution. Pretty much, I have the following formula:

```
=IfError(1/0;"MyError")
```

And I want to change ***"MyError"*** to ***set_error_str*** using the excel Search and Replace option.

What I have tried:

1. plenty of escape inverted commas (I tried with up to 4);
2. CHAR(34);

Note - I am aware how to do it with VBA, but I want a normal user solution with Search and Replace (Ctrl+H). And in the net I found plenty of examples for SUBSTITUTE formula, but this is also not what I want.

Comment: Do you have **set_error_str** created as a named range or defined name?

Comment: Yes. set_error_str is a defined name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

- In the find box enter "MyError" (with the quotes)
- In the replace box enter: set_error_str
- Expand the options and make sure that the *Look in* is set to *Formulas*

[image: Like this]

Now it should work

Comment: Yup, it works for me as well. Strangely, yesterday  I have tried it just once and then I started to think about escaping characters and etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm failing to see the problem. [Ctrl]+H, search for `"MyError")`, replace with `set_error_str)`.

[image: ctrl_H_myerror]
                            <sup>before Find and Replace</sup>

[image: ctrl_H_myerror_after]
                            <sup>after Find and Replace</sup>

Comment: What you've done is not the same as what OP was doing, which presumably was `FindWhat:="MyError"` and `ReplaceWith:="set_error_str"` which will always encapsulate in quotation marks-- good solution though!

Comment: Seems easier/more reliable to use VBA though, expecting ordinary user to remember this, and do it without making mistakes, is a bit of a stretch :)

Comment: This one works as well. Strangely, yesterday I have tried it just once and then I started to think about escaping characters and etc.